# For the use of the LocalizedResourceName property

Tags: windows, dll, desktop.ini

I wish to customize my own folder style, I tried to make the folder get remarks by modifying the `LocalizedResourceName` property in `desktop.ini`.

I try to set `LocalizedResourceName` to a Chinese string. But it is displayed as garbled characters when it is actually displayed.

I noticed the following code in the `desktop.ini` of the system folder:
`LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21798`

So I try to write a .dll file by myself, encapsulate the icon and string, and use it.

I already know how to make a resource-only dll file, but I don't know how to get a certain resource in the file. (ie, get the number `-21798` in the above example code)

How should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By convention, a positive resource number is an index (0 is the first resource etc.) and negative numbers are resource ids. In this specific case, it is the [string resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/strings) with the id of `abs(-21798)` that Windows would pass to `LoadString`.

If you want to create your own .dll, add a string with an id of 2 for example (any number between 2 and 0xffff) and in your .ini you would use `@c:\path\mydll.dll,-2`.

Before you go to all this trouble, just try saving the .ini as UTF-16 LE (Unicode in Notepad) and use Chinese strings directly without the @.

Comment: Thank you!
Now I really can use the strings in my dll. And saving the .ini file as UTF-16 LE is indeed an easier method that I hadn't thought of before.
And by the way, Do you know where there is documentation detailing the entries in the `deaktop.ini` file?
I found the following website:
`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-customize-folders-with-desktop-ini`
But only a limited number of items are introduced.

Comment: Any idea if the list of already used resource id's can be found in the registry? In this case they're related to language, so maybe this one:
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Locale`

Comment: @not Resource Hacker